# Gibberish output with pchart

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, pchart

I  have been trying to create graphs with pchart library in my drupal 7 site. I have installed and configured pchart properly and when I try to test it with an example provided by pcahrt itself am getting a really gibberish output as shown below..

> �PNG  IHDR���R�
>   IDATx��w�\�}��O���^�WH���*\cp��+`'!���M�&N����ɛ8yc'��$؉���`��
>   !PE]��f�����ǕF�٢�jˬt�}��)��g�ܹ��s��������f!�X�0�������jZ�m�@Q�RG�������TӲm_����������Е$$$$$$��K�4t�
>   iVBW�������f%t�
>   iV�Օ�H$r��!x��7?�p������K��'V���7�@,���_~��,>]<����^{�-[�y晧�~���t�3��5Qn:��O�*�y)����&�|A�ҫ�-NN|��g�t�e���2m�nN�#g�wގ#!!!!]����a������zzz���/��59e�ī�������6ؾ}�1Tf�������۷�߸��F���X�<�wy�m��������455}�[ߚ\u%�7��-n�x�pg(xv9~�ۗ_~�;c����1p�>C0�sA�輡"!!!!M��*i�iz͚5p�b@{{;I�޿(��������w�ܹ{��O}�S,�V�V�zOO�Ν;ð��,�SN��4������[�u�]w��?ݹs'�0�v��җ�TYÔ=:�˹)��ttt���ݻw�w�}�emܸq���������ʪh�����sKK��Dfv��TU�09q6�NYp�(
>   ��ǟ|��|�*�|����XUݜ2�ʪ<<�q��o��u�4mwtt466���n���y������r�{��tkk˶m�6n����bc޳go%l��8�lq��لz��]��]ד��u�r3ٙc���*�s6gm�ry��p��8��s������)��9q�ڵg�y��y��j�b��bŊ�'oz�s�i��="" 7ܰcǎ�d��m�p(�j��j�­����k=""
>   u朮g���o������?e+���,{����="{�|�*,|�����N�e���?44t�}�M���"
>   �u~r��%�7�=""
>   v����]9�r��g�*��="">XY�1ض�u�ַ�zˋ��fYv���9ˎO�#�y��?������������Ӏ������4+�}�������f%t�
>   iVBW�������f%t� iVBW�������f%tҀ������4+��$$$$$$�Y
>   �����s��*^bĈ#F�q���4^;�
>   F�1bĈk�q��h#F�1b�5�$�.��r&bĈ#F�qCy!$��JEĈ#F�1�J嵐F�A�1bĈ�2c��H4�#F�1���{ּtv��%�1bĈ#F\�hMbĈ#F�x6���h#F�1b�5�\����f2p�vXu�2��?�ή���#��N�??r[����;3�;ڟ���E�K�
>   bĈ#��3��h�؃S��A*p6��ތ�j��83
>   ��=��rO�eb�#�P�h��rO��9�J*��{�1bĈ/1�ӛ;�5�k�t�����k6����|�����*+15'�qe���mM������:ǤTUq��O#F��%�P��4�?L�<�wy�m��������455}�[ߚ\u

This is very lengthy and am only a piece of the output.

When I put

```
<img src="sites/all/libraries/pChart2.1.3/examples/example.basic.php" />
```

line on my page, am not getting anything, just an empty page with title.

Am getting that gibberish when I include the example.basic.php file on my page.

below is my example.basic.php code,

```
  <?php
     /* CAT:Misc */

    //I have installed libraries module. and the contents of pChart are present in /sites/all/libraries/pChart2.1.3

    $name = "pChart2.1.3";
    if ($path = libraries_get_path($name)) {
     include($path.'/class/pData.class.php');
    include($path.'/class/pDraw.class.php');
    include($path.'/class/pImage.class.php');
    }

     /* Include all the classes 
     include("../class/pDraw.class.php"); 
     include("../class/pImage.class.php"); 
     include("../class/pData.class.php"); */

     /* Create your dataset object */ 
     $myData = new pData(); 

     /* Add data in your dataset */ 
     $myData->addPoints(array(1,3,4,3,5));

     /* Create a pChart object and associate your dataset */ 
     $myPicture = new pImage(700,230,$myData);

     /* Choose a nice font */
     $myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>$path.'/fonts/Forgotte.ttf',"FontSize"=>11));

     /* Define the boundaries of the graph area */
     $myPicture->setGraphArea(60,40,670,190);

     /* Draw the scale, keep everything automatic */ 
     $myPicture->drawScale();

     /* Draw the scale, keep everything automatic */ 
     $myPicture->drawSplineChart();

     /* Render the picture (choose the best way) */
     $myPicture->autoOutput("pictures/example.basic.png");

?>
```

FYI,
I have experimented with rendering the picture such as,

```
$myPicture->autoOutput();

$myPicture->Stroke();

$myPicture->render();
```

But, all of these give the same result..! **So how can I make it work..??**

**///////////////  ADDED image.png code /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="ltr"
  xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
  xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#"
  xmlns:sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#"
  xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">

<head profile="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta about="/d7/?q=node/2" property="sioc:num_replies" content="0" datatype="xsd:integer" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/d7/misc/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<meta content="test" about="/d7/?q=node/2" property="dc:title" />
<link rel="shortlink" href="/d7/?q=node/2" />
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" />
<link rel="canonical" href="/d7/?q=node/2" />
  <title>test | project</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://localhost/d7/modules/system/system.base.css?lzusma");
@import url("http://localhost/d7/modules/system/system.menus.css?lzusma");
@import url("http://localhost/d7/modules/system/system.messages.css?lzusma");
@import url("http://localhost/d7/modules/system/system.theme.css?lzusma");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://localhost/d7/modules/comment/comment.css?lzusma");
@import url("http://localhost/d7/sites/all/modules/date/date_api/date.css?lzusma");
@import url("http://localhost/d7/sites/all/modules/date/date_popup/themes/datepicker.1.7.css?lzusma");
@import url("http://localhost/d7/modules/field/theme/field.css?lzusma");
@import url("http://localhost/d7/modules/node/node.css?lzusma");
@import url("http://localhost/d7/modules/search/search.css?lzusma");
@import url("http://localhost/d7/modules/user/user.css?lzusma");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://localhost/d7/themes/bartik/css/layout.css?lzusma");
@import url("http://localhost/d7/themes/bartik/css/style.css?lzusma");
@import url("http://localhost/d7/themes/bartik/css/colors.css?lzusma");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">@import url("http://localhost/d7/themes/bartik/css/print.css?lzusma");</style>

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/d7/themes/bartik/css/ie.css?lzusma" media="all" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 6]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/d7/themes/bartik/css/ie6.css?lzusma" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/d7/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/d7/misc/jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/d7/misc/drupal.js?lzusma"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/d7\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"bartik","theme_token":"QE-jd8WcXtpZ1dRuiSRy-AooAlkyyPIGI7vF2twO1Js","js":{"misc\/jquery.js":1,"misc\/jquery.once.js":1,"misc\/drupal.js":1},"css":{"modules\/system\/system.base.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.menus.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.messages.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.theme.css":1,"modules\/comment\/comment.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/date\/date_api\/date.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/date\/date_popup\/themes\/datepicker.1.7.css":1,"modules\/field\/theme\/field.css":1,"modules\/node\/node.css":1,"modules\/search\/search.css":1,"modules\/user\/user.css":1,"themes\/bartik\/css\/layout.css":1,"themes\/bartik\/css\/style.css":1,"themes\/bartik\/css\/colors.css":1,"themes\/bartik\/css\/print.css":1,"themes\/bartik\/css\/ie.css":1,"themes\/bartik\/css\/ie6.css":1}}});
//--><!]]>
</script>
</head>
<body class="html not-front not-logged-in one-sidebar sidebar-first page-node page-node- page-node-2 node-type-article" >
  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Skip to main content</a>
  </div>
    <div id="page-wrapper"><div id="page">

  <div id="header" class="without-secondary-menu"><div class="section clearfix">

          <a href="/d7/" title="Home" rel="home" id="logo">
        <img src="http://localhost/d7/themes/bartik/logo.png" alt="Home" />
      </a>

          <div id="name-and-slogan">

                              <div id="site-name">
              <strong>
                <a href="/d7/" title="Home" rel="home"><span>project</span></a>
              </strong>
            </div>


      </div> <!-- /#name-and-slogan -->


          <div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
        <h2 class="element-invisible">Main menu</h2><ul id="main-menu-links" class="links clearfix"><li class="menu-218 first last"><a href="/d7/">Home</a></li>
</ul>      </div> <!-- /#main-menu -->


  </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#header -->



  <div id="main-wrapper" class="clearfix"><div id="main" class="clearfix">

          <div id="breadcrumb"><h2 class="element-invisible">You are here</h2><div class="breadcrumb"><a href="/d7/">Home</a></div></div>

          <div id="sidebar-first" class="column sidebar"><div class="section">
          <div class="region region-sidebar-first">
    <div id="block-user-login" class="block block-user">

    <h2>User login</h2>

  <div class="content">
    <form action="/d7/?q=node/2&amp;destination=node/2" method="post" id="user-login-form" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
  <label for="edit-name">Username <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <input type="text" id="edit-name" name="name" value="" size="15" maxlength="60" class="form-text required" />
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass">
  <label for="edit-pass">Password <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <input type="password" id="edit-pass" name="pass" size="15" maxlength="60" class="form-text required" />
</div>
<div class="item-list"><ul><li class="first"><a href="/d7/?q=user/register" title="Create a new user account.">Create new account</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="/d7/?q=user/password" title="Request new password via e-mail.">Request new password</a></li>
</ul></div><input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-1CLdTDBqbmne6F7FjhizZLAe-9XZmCIa__KHgtmPeP8" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="user_login_block" />
<div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions"><input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Log in" class="form-submit" /></div></div></form>  </div>
</div>
  </div>
      </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#sidebar-first -->

    <div id="content" class="column"><div class="section">
            <a id="main-content"></a>
                    <h1 class="title" id="page-title">
          test        </h1>
                          <div class="tabs">
                  </div>
                          <div class="region region-content">
    <div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system">


  <div class="content">
    <div id="node-2" class="node node-article node-promoted node-full clearfix" about="/d7/?q=node/2" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document">


      <div class="meta submitted">
            <span property="dc:date dc:created" content="2012-02-24T00:32:36+05:30" datatype="xsd:dateTime" rel="sioc:has_creator">Submitted by <span class="username" xml:lang="" about="/d7/?q=user/1" typeof="sioc:UserAccount" property="foaf:name">akshaynhegde</span> on Fri, 02/24/2012 - 00:32</span>    </div>

  <div class="content clearfix">
    <div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded">HELLoo
```

Next part is a gibberish code.. hence I cant paste it so here is the pic of that gibberish code..
[image]

After the gibberish there is some more code.. as below,

```
<img src="/sites/all/libraries/pChart2.1.3/examples/example.basic.php" /></div></div></div>  </div>

      <div class="link-wrapper">
      <ul class="links inline"><li class="comment_forbidden first last"><span><a href="/d7/?q=user/login&amp;destination=node/2%23comment-form">Log in</a> or <a href="/d7/?q=user/register&amp;destination=node/2%23comment-form">register</a> to post comments</span></li>
</ul>    </div>


</div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>

    </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#content -->


  </div></div> <!-- /#main, /#main-wrapper -->


  <div id="footer-wrapper"><div class="section">


          <div id="footer" class="clearfix">
          <div class="region region-footer">
    <div id="block-system-powered-by" class="block block-system">


  <div class="content">
    <span>Powered by <a href="http://drupal.org">Drupal</a></span>  </div>
</div>
  </div>
      </div> <!-- /#footer -->

  </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#footer-wrapper -->

</div></div> <!-- /#page, /#page-wrapper -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what your problem is, seems its outputting a png image, byte-for-byte,
what happens if you add

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.png');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
```

?

Comment: when I try to open the image in firefox afret saving , it gave me following error..  " The image “file:///home/akshay/Downloads/image.png” cannot be displayed because it contains errors. "

Comment: if you open the image.png in a Text-editor,did the png file you downloaded contain any HTML code?

Comment: umm, what was the html code? any chance you can upload the png file somewhere?

Comment: I couldn't upload it as whenever I try to upload it, it says upload failed..! Hence I updated the question and pasted the code above.

Comment: Am familiar with this error , pChart ?? what version of PHP are using ??? Check for Notice: Undefined index: Errors in pChart and in your code ..

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the header information is not being properly set for rendering the image to the browser directly.

Long story chort. Use `$Image->Render("test.png")` instead of `$Image->Stroke()` and make a reference in your page like so:

```
<img src="test.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the implementation of function autoOutput() in the pImage.class.php Line.171.

The action the function performed will be different by the type of interface between Web server and PHP.

Thus the gibberish output is the content of the png file. If you comment all the other html output in your page, you will see a complete image of your chart in the browser.